# Repeated-measures meta-analysis with adjusted post-test means

Tags: repeated-measures, meta-analysis

I am conducting a meta-analysis over pre-test to post-test scores. To this end, I calculate Cohen's d with the following formula:

```
d = (mean_post - mean_pre) / sd(difference scores) * sqrt(2*(1-r))
```

However, one study does not report pre-test scores, but only "post-test means adjusted for pre-test scores". In other words, mean_pre is not provided, but mean_post has been adjusted in some way.

Does this mean that the pre-test scores have been subtracted from the post-test scores? In other words, would it be justified to set mean_pre at zero when using the adjusted post-test means?

Comment: It probably means that pre-test scores were used as a covariate in some kind of regression model.

Comment: So that would mean that the approach that I propose, would not be valid?

Comment: Based on the limited information we have so far I think the answer is probably 'Not valid'. It might help someone to give you a definitive answer if you gave more details in particular what you are going to do with the pre-test means in your meta-analysis.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info. Are you sure that is the right formula if you have the sd(diff)? It looks more like the formula if you only have the pooled sd for the original scores. Anyway in answer to your original question I do not see how you would fit the adjusted means into that framework although others may be able to suggest something. Sorry.

Comment: It should be the right formula, it comes from the Handbook of research synthesis and meta-analysis (2nd edition, page 229).

I believe you are right, thank you for helping me out.